# Get Package Methods and Parameters from Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am looking for the query for Oracle to get all parameters for an Oracle package / procedure.

I know there is a view or table that provides this, but I can't seem to remember what it is.

NOTE: I am not looking for getting a list of packages from user_objects, rather the data type and parameter name for each procedure in a package.

Thanks,

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The view you need is USER_ARGUMENTS (or [ALL_ARGUMENTS](http://oracle.su/docs/11g/server.112/e10820/statviews_1015.htm)).

Comment: Yep... That's what I wanted. Thanks!